# Ajax поиск Woocommerce. Поиск по набору параметров

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, search

Есть у меня вот такие селекты. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге я могу вытащить вот такую информацию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать поиск по этим параметрам если в у товара вот такие атрибуты. Значения не смотрите, это просто пример. Есть товары которые подходят под данную марку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы чтоб результаты поиска были без перезагрузки страницы. 
Задал параметры в селектах, вывел данные по подбору и внизу страницы вывести список товаров которые подходят под эти критерии.

**Сам вопрос, как сделать поиск товаров по атрибутам.** 
*Вообще не знаю как подступиться к WooCommerce. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хоть направление, в какую сторону копать.*

Может есть какое-то тривиальное решение этого вопроса, а я просто не знаю?

Update:
*Я думаю что вполне реально запросом напрямую из базы данных найти все товары, которые нужны. Найти их id. Но потом как заставить WooCommerce их показать?*
Может с помощью шорткода сделать? Вот так?

```
[products ids="1, 2, 3, 4" orderby="rand" order="rand"]
```

Насколько это будет правильно? Какие еще есть варианты? Плагины же эти как-то это делают. Но не через шорткод же...
Как сделать это на более низком уровне?

Comment: Как-от так https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/woocommerce+filter

Comment: А как передать этим плагинам параметры? Может вы не поняли меня? Пользователь выбирает только параметры из селектов, нажимает на кнопку и все. Дальше все делается программно. Я получаю значения пускового тока, размеры, емкость и т.д. для этой конкретной модели, которую выбрал пользователь. Дальше мне нужно найти по этим данным товар, которые подходит под эти параметры. Вот сам поиск как сделать? Плагины фильтры я понимаю. Здесь немного другой вопрос.